# Sending message in a separate thread with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.6, discord.py

I am coding a command (`/mc`, `/` is the prefix) for my discord bot to get and message a result.  But getting the result takes a lot of time.  To prevent  multiple request at a time, I placed the code of getting the results in a separate function `mainmc()` (not `async`) and call `mainmc` as a thread by creating a new class `mainThreadMC(threading.Thread)` to start the thread, and create a new class object and start it, so that when there's multiple request the command will run instantly without having to wait for the previous one.  But quickly after I run it, I've found out that it's not possible as sending a message needs `await` or else it won't work.  But if you have `await` in a function the function needs `async`.  That means I have to edit the module `threading` to make it work?  And surely this is not the way to do it.  But what should I do?

Here's the code (simplified):

```py
class mainThreadMC(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, ctx,args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.ctx = ctx
    def run(self):
        logger.info("Starting " + self.name)
        mainmc(self.ctx,self.args)
        logger.info(f'Exiting {self.name}')

def mainmc(ctx,args):
    # fetching data... creating / editing variable embed
    ctx.send(embed=embed)  #ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!
    # finalize...
    return

@bot.command(name='mc',pass_content=True)
async def mc(ctx,*,args=""):
    global runno
    threadMainMC = mainThreadMC(runno,f"MainMC_{str(runno)}",ctx,args)
    threadMainMC.start()
```

(I just want it to work, so if you have some alternative solutions you can also tell me.)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is it you are trying to do in mainmc? It may be possible to do with the `discord.py` library or with coroutines

Comment: Basically getting the info of Minecraft servers.  Here's the code: [bot.py](https://github.com/windowsboy111/KCCS-official)
I used the library mcstatus to get the info.  It will open ANOTHER THREAD (yeah you heard it right) to get the info.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587063/using-subprocess-to-avoid-long-running-task-from-disconnecting-discord-py-bot/53597795#53597795 It may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried the answer.  When there's multiple request it stills don't process them at the same time despite i can pass back the message.

Comment: Can't your thread return a value then you send it in the command function?

Comment: threads can NOT return values, so i get the value from the thread via editing / getting global values.