# Can't use same discord command twice in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot, which has to do a time-consuming function. But I can only call the command once at a time, otherwise, it will not respond to the messages after it.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@tree.command(
    name = "long-pong",
    description = "long pong"
)

@app_commands.describe(
    nothing = "Nothing",
    toseehere = "to see here"
)

async def requestCalendar(ctx, nothing:str, toseehere:str):
    await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    time.sleep(10)
    await ctx.followup.send("Pong")
```

When I run it a few times at the same moment I get the following error:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'long-pong'
raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062):
Unknown interaction
```

Comment: `time.sleep()` is blocking.

Comment: I understand, it is just an example. It would really be a function that is called. How would I make it so that that function doesn't new requests from coming in?

Comment: Oh, I see. If the task is also blocking, you can try running it with [`run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using Subprocess to avoid long-running task from disconnecting discord.py bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587063/using-subprocess-to-avoid-long-running-task-from-disconnecting-discord-py-bot)

Comment: @thekingoflorda, or maybe check with a simple variable? Disallow execution and notify the user that it's too early to send the consecutive message if the variable is `False`?